# Throw new exception not working when Spring Security enabled

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In my service(it is public route) i am just throw new exception, when customer is already exist

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {
  private final CustomerDataAccess customerDataAccess;
  
  public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> signup(AuthSignUpDto requestCustomer) {
    Optional<Customer> optionalCustomer = this.customerDataAccess.findByEmail(requestCustomer.getEmail());
    if (optionalCustomer.isPresent()) {
      throw new ConflictException("customer [%s] already exist".formatted(requestCustomer.getEmail()));
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Instead of return 400 status with message error, it always return 403 status with no body

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class ConflictException extends RuntimeException{
    private  String message;

    public ConflictException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I am believe when the exception is throwing , spring security interceptor this exception and throw a 403 status, so i am trying to create a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint , and true.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
  
  private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
  private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
  private final AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;
  
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session ->
                    session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .exceptionHandling(exception ->{
              exception.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
            })
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return httpSecurity.build();
  }
}
```

So, how can i throw new exception in Spring Security?

I am trying to disable Spring Security Interceptor and seem it not working, it always return 403 status when exception is throwing.